# Jenkins do not respect LF line terminator on Windows agent

Tags: git, jenkins, line-endings, jenkins-agent

My company use a Linux Jenkins box and the project is forced to use LF or the build will be failed in style checking.
I setup a Windows agent of this Linux Jenkins using "Launch agent via Java Web Start" and Running the Jenkins agent service in this Windows box using a user in its home folder I added one .gitconfig file with the following settings:

```
[core]
        eol = lf
        autocrlf = false
```

And "Source Code Management" setting for the agent's task configuration , I use Git and repository pointing to gitlab repository, so Jenkins will create a workspace in the Windows agent and copy the project over to this workspace. However, I notice that all files change to CRLF.
What I missed? Is this a known issue of Jenkins?

Comment: Did you try to clone with the git program jenkins is using? Can we be sure its jenkins iself? It shouldnt do any modifications, its just issuing a git command... might be a git question not reaching the experts with these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by reinstall a new git with option:
Configuring the line ending conversions to the third option:

`Checkout as-is, commit as is`